# Why First-of-type in ul list is not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists, pseudo-class

#### Code

```css
ul a:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 12</a>
  </li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
</ul>
```

[Result Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzbvvvsp/)

Why is the `a` item 12 selected? It is not the first sibling of its type, it is the last.

Comment: `:first-of-type` refer to the `a` which is` first of type` inside of his `parent`-`li`, so that matches both `a`

Comment: *"...represents the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element."*, it does not select the first element across parents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) refers to the **type** so because `a` is child of the `li`   and as you can see there is **no** more `a` elements as siblings within those `li` so it will select every `first-of-type` of `a` within the `li`

take a look at this snippet with a li with 2 `a` being child of `li` it will select only the first `a`:

#### Snippet

```css
ul a:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3a</a>
    <a href="#">Item 3b</a>
  </li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 12</a>
  </li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
</ul>
```

If you want target only the **item 3**, you can use [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) on `li`, like this:

#### Snippet

```css
ul li:nth-of-type(3) a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 12</a>
  </li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. I was thinking in terms of children not siblings. Makes sense now.